# Issue with Angular material auto resize text-area,

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using variable of min and max rows

```
<textarea #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize" cdkTextareaAutosize 
  [placeholder]="placeholder" [cdkAutosizeMinRows]="cdkAutosizeMinRows" 
  [cdkAutosizeMaxRows]="cdkAutosizeMaxRows">
```

Let's say `cdkAutosizeMaxRows = 10`, `cdkAutosizeMinRows= 2`, the text box renders with height of 2 rows and it never expands

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: Your definition looks fine. Please have a look at following working example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbadbpbgyog?file=app%2Ftext-field-autosize-textarea-example.html